# Setting up Sizers in wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm having trouble setting up my layout using sizers. There will 7 "capsules" that contains a wx.StaticTex for information, a wx.TextCtrl for user input and a icon on right for the visuals. I kind want to leave "more space" for the StaticText if I want to be more verbose about it or I can just choose a smaller font:

[image]

And this is what I've got now:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import wx

class ParametersWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ParametersWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.SetSize((400, 600))
        self.SetTitle(f'{SOFTWARE_NAME}')
        self.Center()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseApp)
        self.setupTextFields()

def setupTextFields(self):
    """ Constroi as caixinhas de texto. """

    self.textBoxesRefs = []

    vWrapperBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    for i in range(0, 7):
        text = self.getTextCtrl()
        text.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnKeyTyped)
        self.textBoxesRefs.append(text)

        vBox = self.getVerticalBox()
        vBox.Add(self.getStaticText(self.getLabel(i)))
        vBox.Add(text, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        hBox = self.getHorizontalBox()
        hBox.Add(vBox, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        image = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        image.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('icons/test.png'))
        hBox.Add(image, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        vWrapperBox.Add(hBox, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

    self.SetSizerAndFit(vWrapperBox)

def getVerticalBox(self):
    """ Retorna a referencia de uma wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL). """

    return wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

def getHorizontalBox(self):
    """ Retorna a referencia de uma wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL). """

    return wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

def getStaticText(self, label):
    """ Retorna a referencia de uma wx.StaticText(). """

    return wx.StaticText(self, label = label)

def getTextCtrl(self):
    """ Retorna a referencia de um wx.TextCtrl. """

    return wx.TextCtrl(self)

def getBitmap(self, path):
    """ Retorna a referencia de um wx.Bitmap(). """

    return wx.Bitmap(path)
```

Is it "savable"?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your question?  It looks like you have something that works.  Are you asking how to make all of the rows the same size?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, sorry for the confusion. In my head, the image would be at the far right and the staticText and textCtrl would be all the same size.

Comment: I think maybe what you're looking for is a [wxFlexGridSizer](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_flex_grid_sizer.html)? Assuming I understood your question correctly... That's the C++ link, but I think it's easy enough to get the Python version working. You could also pass in a constant width size for the wxTextBox?

Comment: Thanks, @segmentation_fault. Putting sizer on stuff close the deal for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I hit my best outcome now. Putting sizers on "stuff" was the key!

*PS: I strip out the unnecessary code.*

```
def setupTextFields(self):
    """ Constroi as caixinhas de texto. """

    self.textBoxesRefs = []

    vWrapperBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    for i in range(0, 7):
        text = self.getTextCtrl()
        text.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnKeyTyped)
        self.textBoxesRefs.append(text)

        vBox = self.getVerticalBox()
        vBox.Add(self.getStaticText(self.getLabel(i)))
        vBox.Add(text)
        vBox.SetMinSize(300, 40)

        hBox = self.getHorizontalBox()
        hBox.Add(vBox, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

        image = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        image.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('icons/test.png'))
        hBox.Add(image)
        vWrapperBox.Add(hBox)

    self.SetSizerAndFit(vWrapperBox)

def getTextCtrl(self):
    """ Retorna a referencia de um wx.TextCtrl. """

    return wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(100, 20))
```

[image]

Can be any better? Of course!

But for now, this is enough.
Thank you all.

Comment: By using the "stretch ratio" parameter when you add to the sizers, you can make the text boxes stretch the entire width.  That would look better to me, but it's personal preference.

Comment: @Tim It really look it nicier. Thanks!